# Is it possible to read xcassets folder in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, bundle, assets, file-manager

I tried using FileManager and Bundle class methods to read Assets.xcassets folder but it returns nil or some other file names. Is it even possible to read that catalog in iOS?

These are the methods I tried:

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
let contents = fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: "")
let contents = contentsOfDirectory(at: assetURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: [URLResourceKey.nameKey, URLResourceKey.isDirectoryKey], options: .skipsHiddenFiles)
let contents = try? fileManager.subpathsOfDirectory(atPath: Bundle.main.resourcePath!)
```

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: interesting question. +1. But why would you need that?

Comment: I want to automate xcassets folder to generate swift file. Script written in Swift is ready but having hard time to read it and don't know if it can even read it. Another viable option is put the assets in normal folder but we don't want to consider the option.

Comment: I don't get what you want.

Comment: anyways, the use case that we use here is not something that could be explained in one or two comments. I would be better off on it. :)

Comment: Well, if people would understand your motives, they could point to alternatives fitting your requirements.

Comment: You can't, compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/30585987/1187415 and the links therein.

Comment: Are you trying to get images? if so you can init an UIImage With UIImage(named: "SomeName")

Comment: @cheesey To get colors

Comment: Have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33351108/get-data-from-xcasset-catalog

Comment: yes, that method gets only data set but not the color set from .xcassets